# Linux and cocos2d: 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, cocos2d-iphone, g++, cocos2d-android, cocos2d-x

I am trying to build a cocos2d sample app for android on linux and i get the following error:

```
stefanos@stefanos-MS-7250:~/cocos2d-1.0.1-x-0.11.0/Test1/android$ ./build_native.sh

    make: Entering directory `/home/stefanos/cocos2d-1.0.1-x-0.11.0/Test1/android'                                                                                                      
    Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3] libs/armeabi/gdbserver                                                                                                               
    Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup                                                                                                                                             
    Compile++ thumb  : cocos2d <= CCConfiguration.cpp  

arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory                                                                           

make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/cocos2d/CCConfiguration.o] Error 1                                                                                                          
make: Leaving directory `/home/stefanos/cocos2d-1.0.1-x-0.11.0/Test1/android'                                                                                                       
stefanos@stefanos-MS-7250:~/cocos2d-1.0.1-x-0.11.0/Test1/android$
```

I am running Ubuntu and i have gcc , g++ installed

**SOLVED:**
It build's fine with the r6 version of the ndk

Download it here :http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r6-linux-x86.tar.bz2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update cocos2d-x [version 2.0](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/news/56), it has been release today, and use [NDK 8](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html). You must be out of date.

Using last version is better, 1.0 has a lot of bugs in Android. One of them with memory manager, it is very bad to release a game in Store.